# Minify HTML code using php but skipping javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, minify, skip

I have this php code which minify all the html output code

```
<?php ob_start(function($b){return preg_replace(['/\s+>[^\S ]+/s','/[^\S ]+\</s','/(\s)+/s'],['>','<','\\1'],$b);}); ?>
```

The thing is i want it to skip all javascript tag. For example skip from `<script>` to `</script>`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Good luck! Do let us know how it turns out

Comment: Well thank you RiggsFolly, but i'm still new here, sorry for my mistake...

Comment: Sorry but your question is not how do I fix my code it is how do I rewrite it to do something comepletely different. That is off topic

Comment: Can't we just modified the code that is on top to exclude JavaScript from it ?

Comment: Here we go again! Yes YOU can.

Comment: I'm not an expert in php, that why i have come here to find out how to make it...